# My ethernet connection is not working but it is detected by my computer

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet

I'm setting up an old computer with ubuntu server 12.04. I wiped the drive and went through the installation fine but afterwards the ethernet would not work. It's physically connected to the router and the card is recognized by lspci(SiS 900) but it won't connect at all. I've plugged in and installed the drivers for a wifi adapter and it's worked with the same router. Just so you know I've turned it on and off plenty of times. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type

```
ifconfig
```

if you can see the line starts from eth0 or something similar

then type

```
dhclient eth0.
```

try

```
ping google.com
```

to check internet connection.

Comment: ifconfig gives me an eth0 and my loopback address. When I dhclient eth0 it hangs for long time but then goes to the prompt with no error. When I ping google it says "unknown host google.com"

Comment: can you post the output of route -n ?

Comment: It says(I added "line break" and the o's for simplicity as comment formatting is difficult): ooooooo
`Kernel IP routing table`  line break oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  `line break oooooooooooooooooo
`0.0.0.0         192.168.15.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0  `line break oooooooooooooooooooooooooo
`192.168.15.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0  `

Comment: Here's it without the o's for easy copying.`Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         192.168.15.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0

192.168.15.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
`

Comment: Try ping -c 5 192.168.15.1 and post out put in here

Comment: Here's a pastebin of it: http://pastebin.com/cMWfj80s

Comment: Post ip address of other machine. 
I'm assuming 192.168.15.1 is the router ip. I want you to check if you can get ping reply from other machine also.

Comment: 192.168.15.206 is another computer on the network and when I ping it I get the exact same answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but I got a new nic card and all is now good. I appreciate your help and I marked your answer right to give you points.

Comment: haha! Couldn't help this time, but glad to hear that new nic works!